# KeyCloak /userinfo not returning user info, returns what appears to be a token

Tags: postman, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

Here is the flow I am attempting in postman.

1. Get access token
   {{server}}/auth/realms/{{realm}}/protocol/openid-connect/token

I get the access token. I then run the next query

2. {{server}}/auth/realms/{{realm}}/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo

I put these in the headers
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: Bearer {{access_token}}

I get a random string in return
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJnN0FHMmJXMmhmQzBLTHJ0S1NUV2V4eTBGWVhsYklybXVEdnF0aDF2MFpNIn0.eyJzdWIiOiIxOGI0OTJhMy0wOGFlLTQ2NjQtODBjNi1iZGQ5Nzk2ODdiMzQiLCJhdWQiOiJibGluZHNwb3QtYXV0aCIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6ODA4MC9hdXRoL3JlYWxtcy9CbGluZHNwb3QifQ.UNyZ2AifgqK9NAiSVwWMFT4_EEleMBztodPHu19NrzIt0DUteK4gfYlgAf-Yfk6w3ue3TyjpD93HFlM-1AG2bHgIyIxI01IbEB2ew9b8xgLiexLrQkgQHIWWWFxSOqQCBo0VPgY3yi0ib3sqeBAcxpvfOhtvQuEH0lHdPFXh8DTJQL18Q3TAhTRpknpwIQ5mpjhaeIW2HXpExrPp6-35r2riPifS_nFNaTqPTSWAFHBiqFEa2_PnQcC6f09jGQYYGkjHnetuAdcmxmhskb59YYlqvRpvezi-Af9IHNhCDad0zomMJK5ajIYUcaXWpAuQZMhPp1OvTB79Olc-YUUOIg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get the user infos you have to make a get Request using this endpoint:{{keycloak_url}}/auth/realms/{{realm}}/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo,
in Authorization : bearen token

Answer (score 1):

Userinfo specification doesn't specify `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header - see https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfoRequest

So use standard GET request `{{server}}/auth/realms/{{realm}}/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo` with `Authorization: Bearer {{access_token}}` header only.

Comment: I removed the content-type and it returns the same information.

Comment: @MichaelMcDermott are you sure you are using current Keycloak version (15)? Are you using access token? You don't have any interceptor (proxy, LB, WAF, ....) between postman & keycloak?

Comment: I am using the current version. I am able to get the token successfully. The return data changes when I update scopes etc in keycloak, but it won't return as a json

Comment: @MichaelMcDermott do you have any mapper on the client level which returns userinfo claim?

Answer (score 1):

To get userInfo as JSON response, make sure "User Info Signed Response Algorithm" is set to "unsigned" in your client settings in Keycloak.

[image]